How do I set timezone in DHCP per RFC 4833 in OpenWRT
I want my DHCP packets to include the time zone per RFC 4833 option 100 or 101.
I logged into the router and ran
dnsmasq --help dhcp

and it shows both:
100 posix-timezone
101 tzdb-timezone

So, I believe this should be supported.
I've tried several syntaxes (one at a time) of
config dnsmasq
    list 'dhcp_option' '101,America/New_York'
    list 'dhcp_option' '101,"America/New_York"'
    list dhcp_option '101,America/New_York'
    list dhcp_option 'tzdb-timezone,America/New_York'

I also tried adding some of them under
config dhcp 'lan'

I then use
service dnsmasq restart

I watch the packets in Wireshark, and I don't see any 101 options being sent. I'm sure this is just my lack of understanding of the syntax.

I think I got it!  Here's the snippet from my /etc/config/dhcp
config dhcp 'lan'
    option interface 'lan'
    option start '30'
    option limit '150'
    option leasetime '12h'
    option dhcpv4 'server'
    list dhcp_option_force '101,"America/New_York"'

My test PC was not asking for the 101 option, so it was not coming through in the packet.  If I add it using the "dhcp_option_force" flag in my configuration, it goes into the DHCP offer regardless.
You can do this from the shell for networks 'lan' and 'guest' with the commands:
uci add_list dhcp.lan.dhcp_option_force='101,"America/New_York"'
uci add_list dhcp.guest.dhcp_option_force='101,"America/New_York"'
uci commit dhcp
service dnsmasq restart

Wireshark shows the packet now includes:
⌄ Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (Offer)
    ⌄ Option: (101) TCode
         Length: 16
         TZ TCode: America/New_York

If your IoT clients are correctly requesting the TCode (101) option in the parameter request list, you do not need the "force". Simply change 'dhcp_option_force' to 'dhcp_option' in the above samples.
